# Setting maven properties depending on the presence of other properties

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a maven property question I can't find referred to in the Docs.
From the command line I will input the property "from.command". This property will always be present.

```
mvn deploy -Dfrom.command=COMMANDVALUE
```

Inside the pom.xml I will specify another property:

```
  <properties>
    <from.pom>POMVALUE</from.pom>
  </properties>
```

This property will some times be there and other times be missing.

I want to have a third property named used.value

I want  used.value to be set to the value of "from.pom" if that property is present otherwise it should be set to the value of "from.command"

This need arrises because I need to run maven builds from another script and I don't want the script to have to inspect all pom files.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [`build-helper-maven-plugin:bsh-property`](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/bsh-property-mojo.html) mojo.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.10</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>bsh-property</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>bsh-property</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <properties>
          <property>used.value</property>
        </properties>
        <source>
          used.value = project.getProperties().getProperty("from.pom", session.getUserProperties().getProperty("from.command"));
        </source>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

This goal enables to write [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/) scripts. It automatically defines the variable `project` as the actual Maven project and `session` as the executing Maven session.

The script above gets the property `"from.pom"` from the Maven project's properties, and defaults to the `"from.command"` property set on the command line. It sets it to the `used.value` variable, which is then exported as a Maven property by the plugin after execution of the script. Command line properties are retrieved from the Maven session with [`getUserProperties()`](http://maven.apache.org/components/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/execution/MavenSession.html#getUserProperties()):

> The user properties have been configured directly by the user on his discretion, e.g. via the `-Dkey=value` parameter on the command line.

This goal automatically binds to the `validate` phase, which is the first phase that is run in the default lifecycle, so you will be able to use `${used.value}` as a property inside the rest of the build.

Comment: That looks like a good answer but my solution must work with windows and Linux

Comment: @Robert3452 This is independant of the system and will work whether on Linux or Windows.

Comment: I assume if I already have another execution in the validate stage I can make this one run before it somehow

Comment: @Robert3452 Yes, you can run it before by placing it before in the POM. For a given phase, Maven executes plugins in the order of their definition in the POM.